# Positioning a button with a tab bar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to position a button but I have found a problem with it.

When the view loads, the button displays but not in the correct position which is just above the tab bar.

```
 self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
 loadButton()
```

When the view did appear method

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            if shouldReloadDataOnViewWillAppear {
                // your code for reloading data
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 2){
                    self.scaleDownAnimation()
                }
                shouldReloadDataOnViewWillAppear = false

            }
        }
```

/////I then call another few functions to set up the map and markers.

Last line of the function sets the tab bar to be hidden:

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
```

then I call the load button function

```
func loadButton()
    {
        if  self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden == false{
        button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named:"compass.png"), for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnPressed), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)

        self.view.addSubview(button)

        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let widthContraints =  NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 40)

        let heightContraints = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 40)

        let xContraints = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.bottomMargin, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.bottomMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: -40)

        let yContraints = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: -40)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([heightContraints,widthContraints,xContraints,yContraints])
        }
    }
```

I think the problem is that the button loads in the correct position but when the tab bar loads it doesn't push up. As you can see below, when the view loads the button is below tab bar and when I segue away from the view it goes to the correct position.

[image]

[image]

I hope this is a really simple problem to solve!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can check this out!

Tested and it worked !

in `viewDidLoad`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        

    //setupViews() after setting up all your Views

    loadButton()
}
```

In `loadButton()`

```
fileprivate func loadButton() {

    if  self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden == false {
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.setImage(UIImage(asset: Asset.Assets.CommonIcons.closeButton), for: .normal) // setup you own Image 
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray // setup you own colour if needed
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 20 // add if needed
        //button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnPressed), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(button)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -40),
            button.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor, constant: -40),
            button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
            button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)
        ])
    }
}
```

Here is the output

[image]

Updated:

Can you please Add a breakpoint to this line

```
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            // =========> Add a breakpoint here 
            button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -40),
            button.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor, constant: -40),
            button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
            button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)
        ])
```

Then run the App, Now you can find whether the method is called before setting up your setupViews !

Or just make some Changes in code as follows

This might work!

Make the constraints for the button in a separate method like below

```
func updateButtonConstraints() {

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

        button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -40),
        button.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor, constant: -40),
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)
    ])
}
```

Then call the `updateButtonConstraints()` in `loadButton()`

```
fileprivate func loadButton() {

        if  self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden == false {
            button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            button.setImage(UIImage(asset: Asset.Assets.CommonIcons.closeButton), for: .normal) // setup you own Image 
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray // setup you own colour if needed
            button.layer.cornerRadius = 20 // add if needed
            //button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnPressed), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
            self.view.addSubview(button)

            updateButtonConstraints()
        }
    }
```

then additionally add the method in

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    updateButtonConstraints()
}
```

Can you check now is it working ?

Comment: Hi there! thank you so much for your detailed response! unfortunelty this does not work and I am unsure why! It works when I navigate away from the screen it goes into the correct position. any other ideas?

Comment: @mick1996 Can you please tell me exactly when you are getting the right position and ur not getting ?

Comment: I get the correct position for the button when I navigate away from page this button is on and navigate back it is in the correct position. I believe that the issue is that the button for some reason doesn't recognise that the tab bar is there. please help

Comment: Here is a screen record of actual problem : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=558gc0QqZ90 As you can see the button is in incorrect position on load but when I navigate to the "local restaurants" page and navigate back the button is in the correct position.

Comment: Can you please add some extra code regarding where are you calling the `loadButton()` method and where do u set navigation and tab bar ?

Comment: @mick1996 I think the method `loadButton()` is called before the tab bar is set to your view controller !

Comment: I have updated the question there with more context and will try your edits now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209385/discussion-between-vicky-vignesh-and-mick1996).

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier for you to reason about your constraints if you used `NSLayoutAnchor` instead of manually creating the constraints:

```
NSLayoutContstraint.activate(
  [
    button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: 40),
    button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: 40),
    button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -40),
    button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -40)
  ]
)
```

This removes a whole bunch of noise from your code so you can more easily see the logic instead of a wall of text with the constraint declarations.

As to your problem, you should probably use the view's safe area instead of the view itself:

```
button.bottomAnchor.constraint(
  equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -40
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately it does not work. I think you are right about pinning it to the safe area. have you any other suggestions that could help me?

Answer (score 1):

```
    if tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden == false {
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named:"compass.png"), for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnPressed), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)

        view.addSubview(button)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
            button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
            button.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -40),
            button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -40)
        ])
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! but the button is now off the screen completely.  I am still new to this and am unsure how to fix?

Comment: @mick1996 When the controller with map is loaded tabView hidden? And at what point do you call the loadButton() function?

Answer (score 1):

Use safeAreaLayoutGuide. bottomLayoutGuide is deprecated:

```
override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()

    view.addSubview(button)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false        
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
        button.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -40),
        button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -40)
    ])
}
```